# iPhone: How to make the Facebook app play videos in HD by default?

Tags: iphone, ios, video, facebook

I have an iPhone 6 and it annoys me that I have to click every time on HD when playing a video before it plays in HD. Does anyone know a way of making sure that all video's played in the FB iPhone app always play in HD?

PS: This feature already works on Facebook in the browser, but I can't find it for the iPhone app..

Comment: i have also same question, did you find answer?